# Listener to getText from element if it's present

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

I was wondering if there's any solution for getting text of a web element if it's present on screen?

Application which I'm automating right now is sometimes displaying unexpected error alert with error code. I want to create a listener that gets the text of the error alert if it's displayed and prints it into console.

I'm using TestNG framework with Selenium WebDriver and Java.

I tried to find any solution on the web but none answered my problem. Only found a way to take screenshot on test fail which is not really solution to my problem.

Comment: You want to get the text of an alert ? If so, then did you try using the Alert class of Selenium to get the text ?

Comment: It's not that kind of alert. It's java scripted web element that shows only in certain situations (if some kind of backend error occurs). Unfortunately Alert class of Selenium is not working in this particular case.

Comment: post HTML code of error

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about a toast message. It's HTML like the rest of the page. You can interact with it as you would any other elements on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Check the length count of the WebElements.If length count more than 0 then fetch the text of the element.Let me know how it goes. check the `text` if returns null then try `innerHTML` property.

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        List<WebElement> errelements =wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("xpath of locator")));
        if(errelements.size()>0)
        {
         System.out.println(errelements.get(0).getText()); 
         System.out.println(errelements.get(0).getAttribute("innerHTML"));  
        }
```